# Fetch function never catches error, always runs then(() => block) with undefined response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Im returning fetch function from separate callApi layer, and calling then + catch for it.

Callapi.js

```
export const callApi = (url, options = {}, headers = {}) => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      ...headers,
    },
    ...options,
  };

  return fetch(url, defaultOptions)
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw Error(res.statusText);
      }
      if(res.status === 401)
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}

export default callApi;
```

Component.js

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(loginInfo)
    callApi('http://localhost:8080/login',{
        method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: loginInfo.email,
            password: loginInfo.password,
      }),
    })
      .then((res => {
          console.log(res)
          setRedirect(true)
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => setError(err)))
  }
```

Im having a hard time understanding why catch block doesn't fire, when I throw new error, but then block with undefined response fires always.
Thanks for your help

Comment: in your catch try to return the error

Comment: What i can see from your code is that if response is correct, you are returning "res", but in catch you are not returning or throwing anything!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's to do with this block:

```
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

As the error is caught it's considered handled and therefor will pass through to the next `.then()` in `handleSubmit`

If logging the error is essential in `callApi` you could consider re-throwing the error

```
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! You all were right, but I mark this one as correct since it was first one. This was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What i can see from your code is that if response is correct, you are returning "res", but in catch you are not returning or throwing anything which lead promise to pass in .then()

```
 .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.catch()` in *Callapi.js* will catch all errors thrown from prior `.then()` in the same file. Therefore, no errors will happen in *Component.js*.

Try either re-throwing error, [as Ross Mackay suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780882/fetch-function-never-catches-error-always-runs-then-block-with-undefined/63780932#63780932), or moving the `.catch()` block to *Component.js*, — whatever suites you the best.